# Finding Area of the red square

Tags: geometry

Calculate the area of the red square.

I m having some trouble doing it so I need some help.

[image: Figure]

Comment: Where's the square? :)

Comment: I have added the link

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: what have you tried so far? I guess it is going to be easier for others to help if they know your attempts. This will also avoid downvoting.

Comment: I m not able to figure the angle made by SOB when S is connected to O

Comment: Otherwise i m done

Comment: I have got an equation relating the side of the square and angle SOB

Comment: I proceeded in a slighlty different way. I'll share it with you: call $x$ the abscissa of $P$ and $R$, and $r$ the radius of the bigger circle ($r = 7$). Euclid's theorem gives you ordinate of $P$, since it lies on a circle of radius $\frac{r}{2}$. Switch abscissa and ordinate to obtain coordinates of $S$, and thus the side of the square as a function of $x$. Then consider determing the diagonal of the square by subtracting to ordinate of $P$ to that of $R$ (which is known, as a function of $x$). Having both diagonal and side as a function of $x$ you got an equation. How's that?

Comment: Will P and R have same abscissa?

Comment: Consider drawing the quadrant bisector. You'll notice the simmetry of $S$ and $P$, and that of $R$ and $Q$ with respect to the bisector. Can you conclude something about the reciprocal position of $R$ and $P$?

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a solution

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you have troubles with that approach. I'll scketch an answer with more details, if no one else does in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(with slightly different point labels)

[image]

Introduce $a$ as the radius of the big circle and $d$ as the side of the square. Take $O$ as the origin of the coordinate system with $x$ axis going to the right and $y$ axis going upwards. We have the foolowing point coordinates:

$$H(x_H, y_H)$$

Note that $x_H>y_H$. Because of symmetry:

$$G(x_G,y_G)\equiv G(y_H,x_H)$$

So the side of the square is:

$$d=\sqrt{(x_G-x_H)^2+(y_G-y_H)^2}=\sqrt{(y_H-x_H)^2+(x_H-y_H)^2}=\sqrt{2}(x_H-y_H)\tag{1}$$

Coordinates of point $I$ are:

$$I(x_I,y_I)\equiv I(x_H+d\frac{\sqrt 2}{2},y_G)\equiv I(x_H+(x_H-y_H), x_H)\equiv I(2x_H-y_H, x_H)$$

Point $H$ is on the small circle so:

$$(x_H-\frac a2)^2+y_H^2=(\frac a2)^2\tag{2}$$

Point $I$ is on the big circle so:

$$(2x_H-y_H)^2+x_H^2=a^2\tag{3}$$

So you have a system with of two equations, (2) and (3), with two unknowns $(x_H,y_H)$. The system leads to the following quartic equation for $a=7$:

$$32x_H^4-56x_H^3-343x_H^2-686x_H+2401=0$$

In theory, you can solve it by hand. I did it with Mathematica:

$$x_H=4.40864,\ \ y_H=3.38$$

Other solutions had to be discarded (two of them are complex, the third one leads to negative value of $y_H$). From (1):

$$d=1.45471$$

...which is pretty much in sync with the value obtained by measuring the length of the square in Geogebra.